# Stack trace in SQL Server for Linux

Tags: linux, sql-server-2017

Does somebody know what´s the reason of this stacktrace?

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU3-GDR) (KB4052987) - 14.0.3015.40 (X64)    
Dec 22 2017 16:13:22   
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation 
Web Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: #015This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running.
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: The following diagnostic information is available:
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:        Reason: 0x00000006
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:        Status: 0xc0000005
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:       Message: Last Chance
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:       Address: 0x6a446912
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:    Parameters: 0x70373f270
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: #015               #015               #015   Stacktrace: 000000006a4e84f6 000000006a43fb1e 000000006a43f9ca
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:                000000006a518473 000000006a446912
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: #015      Process: 5447 - sqlservr
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:        Thread: 5662 (application thread 0x132c)
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:   Instance Id: c0074e4f-7ce0-43ef-bbc1-c9f5caecdfb6
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:      Crash Id: 1839d4f4-07d4-4a59-b4f8-894c6f19a995
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:   Build stamp: 0fa9143612e88b9b2379174bbdc492bbfae2bec2f0278445d22e11dd124604ab
Jan 30 10:18:51 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: Capturing core dump and information...
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:       Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:       turn off this notice.
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:       Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:       turn off this notice.
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: tail: no se puede abrir '/var/log/syslog' para lectura: Permiso denegado
Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: Attempting to capture a dump with paldumper
Jan 30 10:18:58 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: Core dump and information are being compressed in the background. When
Jan 30 10:18:58 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: complete, they can be found in the following location:
Jan 30 10:18:58 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]:   /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.01_30_2018_10_18_51.5447.tbz2
Jan 30 10:18:58 cambalacheBD systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 30 10:18:58 cambalacheBD systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 30 10:18:58 cambalacheBD systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 30 10:18:58 cambalacheBD systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 30 10:18:58 cambalacheBD systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

Comment: Which user are you using
 No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions. Jan 30 10:18:53 cambalacheBD sqlservr[5445]: tail: no se puede abrir '/var/log/syslog' para lectura: Permiso denegado

Comment: If you're the same user as https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/71346/krismorte you should ask Stack Exchange to merge the accounts.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198650/sql-server-crash-with-reason-0x00000006-after-a-while-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

There is never enough information with these crash logs. Often, all you can do is drop the database and start over -- access to the tools that would otherwise assist in trouble shooting this are disabled by Microsoft, such as `strace` and `ltrace`. You can [roll your own kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/413697/3285) if you're in need of more information.

- You may also try [running this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194693/2639) to reset the permissions on the system if they're misconfigured.
- Remember that the right user for the server is always `mssql`. You **must** use that `mssql` user.
- You have to have the server licensed properly (even if you just use the configuration utility to tell it you're a developer). Without proper licensing, you may get weird and unexplainable errors including segfaults.