# SQL Server crash with Reason 0x00000006 after a while on linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, full-text-search, errors, sql-server-2017

### Environment

- OS

  - Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 (also happening on Windows)
- DB

  - SQL Server **2017** with **FullText Search module** (mssql-server and mssql-server-fts packages)

### Problem

The issue that I'm facing is that, after a while (I didn't find a pattern yet, but it happens from times to times... last time the database was in IDLE with just a [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) connection), the server crashes with a fatal error as follows:

```
mssql_1      | This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running.
mssql_1      | The following diagnostic information is available:
mssql_1      | 
mssql_1      |        Reason: 0x00000006
mssql_1      |        Status: 0xc0000005
mssql_1      |       Message: Last Chance
mssql_1      |       Address: 0x6a446912
mssql_1      |    Parameters: 0x802cef270
   Stacktrace: 000000006a4e84f6 000000006a43fb1e 000000006a43f9ca 
mssql_1      |                000000006a518473 000000006a446912 
      Process: 9 - sqlservr
mssql_1      |        Thread: 175 (application thread 0x1288)
mssql_1      |   Instance Id: 7eb1810a-0fbe-42f1-bb07-a0f20f7f3dcf
mssql_1      |      Crash Id: bec85ffc-9907-4f7b-a7bd-bd17e0c90561
mssql_1      |   Build stamp: 0fa9143612e88b9b2379174bbdc492bbfae2bec2f0278445d22e11dd124604ab
mssql_1      | 
mssql_1      | Capturing core dump and information...
mssql_1      | No journal files were found.
mssql_1      | No journal files were found.
mssql_1      | Attempting to capture a dump with paldumper
mssql_1      | WARNING: Capture attempt failure detected
mssql_1      | Attempting to capture a filtered dump with paldumper
mssql_1      | WARNING: Attempt to capture dump failed.  Reference /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.9.temp/log/paldumper-debug.log for details
mssql_1      | Attempting to capture a dump with gdb
mssql_1      | WARNING: Unable to capture crash dump with GDB. You may need to
mssql_1      | allow ptrace debugging, enable the CAP_SYS_PTRACE capability, or
mssql_1      | run as root.
```

[this error reasons table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx) (am I looking at the correct table?) points that:

**Reason: 0x00000006** - The handle is invalid.

**Message: Last Chance**

I have no clue what is going on... so... Does anyone knows what is the real reason of the error here?

Any suggestions on how can I get more debug/runtime info in order to trace what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

### [Update 1] It also happens on Windows:

This is also happening on SQL Server **2017** on Windows.

Comment: Can you get a memory dump from the windows crash?

Comment: I have a core mem dump from linux. But I can see if I can get a dump from windows too

Answer (score 1):

### Partial Solution:

Downgrading to SQL Server 2008 solves the issue.

### PS.:

Posting this as an answer just because, depending on the project needs, this may be enough.

But a solution to the SQL Server 2017 version is still needed though...

Comment: Did you test that all intermediate versions (2016, 2014, 2012, 2008R2) crash, too?

Comment: Unfortunately no... it can be an interesting test, but it's a bit laborius (atm).