# Cannot systemctl start/stop mssql. mssql-server stuck in script upgrade mode. Cannot login either

Tags: sql-server, linux

I'm having trouble getting my mssql-server back online. Apparently it got stuck between an upgrade and a bad database restore, and now it is stuck, and I nothing I've tried has helped to unstuck it.

Basically I was doing a

```
RESTORE DATABASE ···· FROM DISK = '/path/to/backup/·······.bak'
WITH replace, move '········' TO
'/path/to/data/········.mdf', move '······' TO
'/path/to/data/······.ldf'
GO
```

that got stuck (`The database '····' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that does not allow recovery to be run`), and by some idiotic timing, minutes later  a `yum update` took place, including an `mssql-server` upgrade. After that, I got locked out of the server and now I cant do anything to get in.

If I type

```
systemctl start/stop mssql-server
```

the command never finishes, and when I `ctrl-C` it,

```
systemctl status mssql-server
```

returns

```
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since sat 2019-05-18 20:49:33 MST; 4min 0s ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
 Main PID: 5864 (sqlservr)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
       ├─5864 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
       └─5866 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

Apparently, it never finishes deactivating, and after a short while, `systemctl status` sends

```
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since sáb 2019-05-18 20:27:35 MST; 17min ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
 Main PID: 5864 (sqlservr)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
       ├─5864 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
       └─5866 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

when I try to login as admin I get

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response.
```

and `/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog` reads

```
Login failed for user '####'. Reason: Server is in script upgrade mode. Only administrator can connect at this time. [CLIENT: #######]
```

and when I try login as a regular user, I get

I've tried the solutions proposed in [SqlServer is in script upgrade mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975286/sqlserver-is-in-script-upgrade-mode) which is just to wait (two days in my case), [Can't connect to mssql server on ubuntu because script is in upgrade mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132534/cant-connect-to-mssql-server-on-ubuntu-because-script-is-in-upgrade-mode), which suggests typing

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf traceflag 902 on
sudo systemctl start mssql-server
```

[SQL Server 2017 on Linux in script upgrade mode after update](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185045/sql-server-on-linux-hangs-on-initial-startup-no-errors-and-no-new-updated-er), which suggest typing

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set sqlagent.enabled true
sudo systemctl start mssql-server
```

and [SQL Server on Linux hangs on initial startup, no errors, and no new / updated ErrorLog file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185045/sql-server-on-linux-hangs-on-initial-startup-no-errors-and-no-new-updated-er), which suggests changing ownership permissions,

```
sudo chown -R  mssql:mssql /var/opt/mssql
sudo systemctl start mssql-server
```

but nothing has worked so far. The complete `errorlog` reads (please help me remove sensitive information if I left some)

```
 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU14) (KB4484710) - 14.0.3076.1 (X64) 
     Mar 12 2019 19:29:19 
     Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
     Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (CentOS Linux 7 (Core))
 Server      UTC adjustment: -7:00
 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
 Server      All rights reserved.
 Server      Server process ID is 32.
 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
      -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
      -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
      -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
 Server      SQL Server detected 2 sockets with 6 cores per socket and 12 logical processors per socket, 24 total logical processors; using 8 logical processors based      on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 Server      Detected 6554 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary. 
 Server      InitializeExternalUserGroupSid failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
 Server      Implied authentication manager initialization failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
 Server      Successfully initialized the TLS configuration. Allowed TLS protocol versions are ###############################################################.
 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA      configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No      user action is required.
 Server      Lock partitioning is enabled.  This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on lowend machine.
 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL      Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
 spid6s      Starting up database 'master'.
 spid6s      12 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid6s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid6s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid6s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
 spid6s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
 spid6s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
 spid6s      Server name is '###'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid23s     Always On: The availability replica manager is starting. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid21s     Starting up database '####'.
 spid22s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
 spid9s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
 spid23s     Always On: The availability replica manager is waiting for the instance of SQL Server to allow client connections. This is an informational message only.      No user action is required.
 spid9s      The resource database build version is 14.00.3076. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid9s      Starting up database 'model'.
 spid21s     The database '####' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that does not allow recovery to be run.
 spid22s     20 transactions rolled forward in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid9s      Polybase feature disabled.
 spid22s     0 transactions rolled back in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid9s      Clearing tempdb database.
 spid22s     Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'msdb' (4). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid18s     A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
 spid18s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> ####].
 spid18s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> ####].
 spid18s     Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated      administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 2019-05-18 20:27:39.32 Server      Failed to verify the Authenticode signature of 'C:\binn\secforwarder.dll'. Signature verification of SQL Server DLLs will be skipped. Genuine copies of SQL Server are signed. Failure to verify the Authenticode signature might indicate that this is not an authentic release of SQL Server. Install a genuine copy of SQL Server or contact customer      support.
 spid9s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
 spid21s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
 spid21s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
 spid21s     Service Broker manager has started.
 spid6s      Database 'master' is upgrading script 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' from level 234884072 to level 234884100.
 spid6s      ----------------------------------
 spid6s      Starting execution of PRE_MSDB.SQL
 spid6s      ----------------------------------
 spid6s      Setting database option COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL to 100 for database 'msdb'.
 spid6s      -----------------------------------------
 spid6s      Starting execution of PRE_SQLAGENT100.SQL
 spid6s      -----------------------------------------
 spid6s      Setting database option COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL to 140 for database 'msdb'.
 spid6s      Configuration option 'allow updates' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
 spid6s      Configuration option 'allow updates' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
 spid6s      Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
 spid6s      Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2017.140.3076' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user      action is required.
 spid6s      DBCC TRACEOFF 1717, server process ID (SPID) 6. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
 spid6s      DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating table temp_sysjobschedules
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Alter table sysdownloadlist...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Alter table sysjobhistory...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Alter table systargetservers...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Alter table sysjobsteps...
 spid6s      Configuration option 'allow updates' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
 spid6s      Configuration option 'allow updates' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
 spid6s       
 spid6s      -----------------------------------------
 spid6s      Execution of PRE_SQLAGENT100.SQL complete
 spid6s      -----------------------------------------
 spid6s      DMF pre-upgrade steps...
 spid6s      DC pre-upgrade steps...
 spid6s      Check if Data collector config table exists...
 spid6s      Data Collector state before upgrade: 0
 spid6s      pre_dc100::Check if syscollector_collection_sets_internal table exists...
 spid6s      pre_dc100::Capturing Collection set status in temp table...
 spid6s      Deleting cached auto-generated T-SQL Data Collection packages from msdb...
 spid6s      End of DC pre-upgrade steps.
 spid6s      DAC pre-upgrade steps...
 spid6s      Starting DAC pre-upgrade steps ...
 spid6s      End of DAC pre-upgrade steps.
 spid6s      ----------------------------------
 spid6s      Starting execution of MSDB.SQL
 spid6s      ----------------------------------
 spid6s      Configuration option 'allow updates' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
 spid6s      Configuration option 'allow updates' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
 spid6s      Checking the size of MSDB...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Setting database option TRUSTWORTHY to ON for database 'msdb'.
 spid6s      Setting database option RECOVERY to SIMPLE for database 'msdb'.
 spid6s      ----------------------------------
 spid6s      Finished execution of MSDB.SQL
 spid6s      ----------------------------------
 spid6s      -----------------------------------------
 spid6s      Starting execution of MSDB_VERSIONING.SQL
 spid6s      -----------------------------------------
 spid6s      -----------------------------------------
 spid6s      Finished execution of MSDB_VERSIONING.SQL
 spid6s      -----------------------------------------
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_agent_add_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_agent_delete_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_agent_add_jobstep...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_agent_start_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_agent_get_jobstep...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_agent_log_job_history...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_agent_write_sysjobstep_log...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating table syssubsystems...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating view sysproxyloginsubsystem_view...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating trigger trig_sysoriginatingservers_delete...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating view sysoriginatingservers_view...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating trigger trig_sysjobs_insert_update...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating view sysjobs_view...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating trigger trig_sysschedules_insert_update...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating view sysschedules_localserver_view...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating view systargetservers_view...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating view sysalerts_performance_counters_view...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating function SQLAGENT_SUSER_SNAME ...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating function SQLAGENT_SUSER_SID ...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure SP_SQLAGENT_IS_SRVROLEMEMBER...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_get_traceflag_status_internal...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_category_identifiers...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating function agent_datetime...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_proxy_identifiers...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_credential_identifiers...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_subsystems...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_subsystem_identifiers...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_login_identifiers...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_proxy...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_proxy...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_proxy...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_proxy...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_is_member...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_proxy_permissions...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_proxy...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_get_proxy_properties...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_grant_login_to_proxy...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_revoke_login_from_proxy...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_revoke_proxy_from_subsystem...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_enum_proxy_for_subsystem...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_enum_login_for_proxy...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_reassign_proxy...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_get_startup_info...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_has_server_access...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_get_perf_counters...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_notify...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_is_sqlagent_starting...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_job_identifiers...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_schedule_identifiers...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_jobproc_caller...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_downloaded_row_limiter...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_post_msx_operation...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_performance_condition...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_job_date...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_job_time...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_alert...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_alert...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_job_references...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_all_msx_jobs...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_generate_target_server_job_assignment_sql...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_generate_server_description...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_msx_set_account...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_msx_get_account...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_operator...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_msx_defect...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_msx_enlist...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_targetserver...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_enlist_tsx
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_get_sqlagent_properties...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Create procedure sp_set_sqlagent_properties...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_targetservergroup...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_targetservergroup...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_targetservergroup...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_targetservergroup...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_targetsvgrp_member...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_targetsvrgrp_member...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_category...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_category...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_category...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_category...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_category...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_targetserver...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_resync_targetserver...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_purge_jobhistory...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_jobhistory...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_jobserver...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_jobserver...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_jobserver...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_downloadlist...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_enum_sqlagent_subsystems_internal...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_enum_sqlagent_subsystems...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_subsystem...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_schedule...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_schedule...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_attach_schedule ...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_detach_schedule ...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_replication_job_parameter...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_schedule ...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_schedule ...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_get_jobstep_db_username...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_jobstep...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_jobstep_internal...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_jobstep...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_jobstep...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_jobstep...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_jobstep...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_write_sysjobstep_log...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_jobsteplog...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_jobsteplog...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_get_schedule_description...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_jobschedule...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_jobschedule...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_jobschedule...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_schedule...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_jobschedule...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_get_composite_job_info...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_jobcount...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_jobs_in_schedule...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_manage_jobs_by_login...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_apply_job_to_targets...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_remove_job_from_targets...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_get_job_alerts...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_start_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_stop_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_cycle_agent_errorlog...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_get_chunked_jobstep_params...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_check_for_owned_jobs...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_check_for_owned_jobsteps...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_refresh_job...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_jobhistory_row_limiter...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure [dbo].[sp_sqlagent_set_job_completion_state]...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure [dbo].[sp_sqlagent_set_jobstep_completion_state]...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure [dbo].[sp_sqlagent_create_jobactivity]...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure [dbo].[sp_sqlagent_update_jobactivity_next_scheduled_date]...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure [dbo].[sp_sqlagent_update_jobactivity_requested_date]...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure [dbo].[sp_sqlagent_update_jobactivity_queued_date]...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure [dbo].[sp_sqlagent_update_jobactivity_start_execution_date]...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_log_jobhistory...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_check_msx_version...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_probe_msx...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_set_local_time...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_multi_server_job_summary...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_target_server_summary...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating [legacy] procedure sp_uniquetaskname...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating [legacy] procedure sp_addtask...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating [legacy] procedure sp_droptask...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating trigger trig_targetserver_insert...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_alert_internal...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_alert...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_alert...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_alert...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_operator...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_operator...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_operator...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_operator...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_help_operator_jobs...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_operator_identifiers...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_notify_operator...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_verify_notification...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_add_notification...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_update_notification...
 spid6s       
 spid6s      Creating procedure sp_delete_notification...
 Logon       Error: 18401, Severity: 14, State: 1.
 Logon       Login failed for user '#####'. Reason: Server is in script upgrade mode. Only administrator can connect at this time. [CLIENT: ########]
```

In line 45 of `errorlog`, it says

```
spid21s     The database '####' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that does not allow recovery to be run.
```

And I cant go forward nor backwards. I even tried to reinstall mssql-server but it also gets stuck `Running Transactions`.

Any advice?

### EDIT

I think it has something to do with security. Now `systemctl stop mssql-server` works but it takes forever, and I cannot login remotely. The following errors occur

```
Logon       SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090308, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The operating system error code indicates the cause of failure. The token supplied to the function is invalid   [CLIENT: ######]
Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. [CLIENT: #######]
spid51      Attempting to load library 'xplog70.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
Using 'xplog70.dll' version '2017.140.3076' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Sadly, I've been unable to find relevant information on how to fix this errors.

Answer (score 3):

I was having similar issue to a point where I could not even connect. Turns out there are two different version streams (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-change-repo?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=ld2-ubuntu#cuversusgdr):

1. **Cumulative Updates (CU)**: The Cumulative Update (CU) repository contains packages for the base SQL Server release and any bug fixes or improvements since that release. Cumulative updates are specific to a release version, such as SQL Server 2017. They are released on a regular cadence.
2. **GDR**: The GDR repository contains packages for the base SQL Server release and only critical fixes and security updates since that release. These updates are also added to the next CU release.

Looks like it is more stable to use GDR in prod. "Downgrading" at least solved all my issues.

Answer (score 1):

This command helped me and then finaly I can login on SQL Server in Red Hat 8.

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf traceflag 902 on

sudo systemctl start mssql-server
```

from [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/use-trace-flag-902-tf902-to-bring-up-your-sql-service-in-failed/ba-p/2963393) Microsoft TechCommunity Page:

> TF902 as a quick workaround to bring up your SQL Server service if it fails to be started due to post upgrade script failure after installing SQL Server patch. Further troubleshooting steps to address the post upgrade script failure have been discussed in later part of this article.
>
> Please be noted that it is not suggested to keep your SQL Server service in this state for long since your SQL Server is in an incomplete patch installation status and considered instable for your production environment.